# ImportError: cannot import name 'OAuthHandler'

Tags: python, python-3.x, twitter, tweepy

```
import tweepy

consumerKey = "MGjdrqvqer1hSiQcmKp6Oxwea"
consumerSecret = "vGKoEvJdpooSSn8a0lh4Fp51fFX6wK6qoRzx8QJvPEAecAg6mE"

auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler(consumerKey,consumerSecret)

accessToken = "886183447596638209-gu896OPrhbiW1IlUft7kwvkalrEgMTE"
accessTokenSecret = "kqmMkSKg0sa8DGzPOi8WbHlpMGghi8STj6M3ofo9XLx18"

auth.set_access_token(accessToken, accessTokenSecret)

api = tweepy.API(auth)


tweet = " ABCDE "
api.update_status(status=tweet)

print("Success")
print()
```

I runed it, but error comes out every time.
I reinstall it, but it dosen't get better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to import the `OAuthHandler` attribute directly from the `tweepy.auth`:

```
from tweepy.auth import OAuthHandler

consumerKey = "MGjdrqvqer1hSiQcmKp6Oxwea"
consumerSecret = "vGKoEvJdpooSSn8a0lh4Fp51fFX6wK6qoRzx8QJvPEAecAg6mE"

auth = OAuthHandler(consumerKey, consumerSecret)

accessToken = "886183447596638209-gu896OPrhbiW1IlUft7kwvkalrEgMTE"
accessTokenSecret = "kqmMkSKg0sa8DGzPOi8WbHlpMGghi8STj6M3ofo9XLx18"

auth.set_access_token(accessToken, accessTokenSecret)
```